# Calling a function from ng-click with $scope.var as parameter

Tags: angularjs

I had this problem when calling a function from ng-click using $scope.var as parameter.

For instance:

Not Working:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in values track by $index">
        <a ng-click="function({{ value }})">{{ value }}</a>
</div>
```

Working:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in values track by $index">
        <a ng-click="function(value)">{{ value }}</a>
</div>
```

Why we can't use {{ }} if the variable is from $scope, declared on an Angular controller? Is there others situations when I will not use it?

Comment: if you're new on angular i would recommend you read this style guide
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not use expressions in directives like ng-click.
Expression can access variables and functions from the scope.
while using it in function, there is no need to write expression

Answer (score 0):

First thing `function is in built keyword`.You can not use it.

suppose in controller you defined function like this.

```
$scope.callMe = function(){

}
```

then define the html :

```
<div ng-repeat="value in values track by $index">
        <a ng-click="callMe(value)">{{ value }}</a>
</div>
```